# Change Sticky bit with Java

Tags: java, file-io

Is there any way to add/remove the sticky bit (S_ISVTX) on a file and a directory with Java ?

Comment: @jweyrich : when I say 'sricky bit' , I think about S_ISVTX (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) not sticky bits in the IEEE 754 Standard... But thanks !

Comment: oh, I understood it. I actually misread the bug report. Removing my useless comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Call out to the /bin/chmod command. Since this sticky bit is platform specific Java will not provide a standard library API for it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-programmer/6733/Modifying-read-only-files-in-Java) it's is not possible directly but however you can workaround if you have sufficient permissions to delete. In a gist, you 'll have to read the file, delete it and write it back with modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I've already has the same problem. At first, I use Runtime to exe chmod command, it works but I don't know why after some days, my program usually die without any reason. My program is simple, so I think there's something like memory,resource leak when use Runtime.exec in java.
Later, I switch to use [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) to direct call to libc function, it works well till now.